# Search mysql if json key not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, json

I've got a json string stored in a mySQL DB and now I'm trying to find a way to check if a specific key contains a value at all or not.

Been googling around, but most solutions point to finding a specific value, where instead I want to check if there's a value there or not.

This is to be implemented into some sort of php check function, and if there's a way to get all results from mysql instead of doing multiple queries, that'd be great.

Example:

```
row 1 {"Name":"Jane","Group":"","customernumber":"12345"}
row 2 {"Name":"Mike","Group":"Sales","customernumber":"23456"}
row 3 {"Name":"Steve","Group":"","customernumber":"34567"}
```

The resulting array would contain Mike with details and so on.

A little help, please?

---

**EDIT**

- I didn't choose to store the data like this. It's the CMS I'm working with that stores custom form like this.

I've got about 400 db entries and I thought of letting MySQL do the processing since I don't know if storing that many results in an array would be bad for performance since a couple of users are going to view pages that uses these results causing quite frequent requests.

Comment: "now I'm trying to find a way to check if a specific key contains a value at all or not" --- now you know, that storing json in a string column is a **bad** idea

Comment: Ideally you should create another table that contains these associations.

Comment: Oh dear... using mysql as a mongodb collection? Why?

Comment: Should add that it's nothing I've chosen to do. It's the CMS I'm working with that stores custom forms like that.